# AngularJS : How do I nest a view within a parent state with parameters?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I'm using the Ionic Framework to create a mobile app, but I'm having a difficult time with the UI Router.  I've gotten a few screens working properly, but I can't seem to get nested views working on a state with parameters.  I'd like a URL that looks like `/legislator/1/profile`.  It would have a header with the name of legislator #1 and tabs below.  The profile tab would be automatically visible and clicking on other tabs (e.g. `/legislator/1/votes`) would change the content, but not the header

I wound up abandoning the tabs & sidemenu starter projects to customize my nested views.  Here's what I have in app.js.  The home and people.* states work correctly, but I can't seem to load the legislator screen with the profile view in place.  I've tried changing the abstract & controller attributes, but no luck yet.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

  .state('home', {
    url: "/home",
    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
    controller: "homeController"
  })

  .state('people', {
    url: "/people",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/people.html"
  })

  .state('people.legislators', {
    url: "/legislators",
    templateUrl: "templates/legislators.html",
    controller: "legislatorController"
  })

  .state('people.following', {
    url: "/following",
    templateUrl: "templates/following.html",
    controller: "followingController"
  })

  .state('legislator', {
    url: "/legislator/{legislatorId:int}",
    templateUrl: "templates/legislator.html",
    abstract: true
  })

  .state('legislator.profile', {
    url: "/legislator/{legislatorId:int}/profile",
    templateUrl: "templates/legislator.profile.html",
    controller: "profileController"
  })

  .state('legislator.votes', {
    url: "/legislator/{legislatorId:int}/votes",
    templateUrl: "templates/legislator.votes.html",
    controller: "votelistController"
  })

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fall-back
})
```

How is this scenario supposed to work in the UI Router?  Once I have $stateProvider configured, how should the tabs link to the nested states?

Thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your solution is as simple as replacing the classic href by [Ui Router's ui-sref](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref):

replace

```
<ion-tab ... href="#/legislator/{ scopeLegislatorId }/profile">...</ion-tab>
```

by

```
<ion-tab ... ui-sref="legislator.profile({ legislatorId: scopeLegislatorId })">...</ion-tab>
```

Where `scopeLegislatorId` is the legislatorId, available from your scope.

If that doesn't help, please provide us with your html files (e.g. `legislator.html` and `legislator.profile.html`).

Comment: Your ui-sref links work for the tabs that are on the legislator screen, but the same link won't work from other screens in the app.  I have a list of names on a screen with state people.legislators and I've tried both of the links above and every other I can think of, but it only ever takes me to legislator/1, never legislator/1/profile.  To see the profile template in the nested view, I need to click the "Profile" tab after the legislator state is loaded.  I would add my template code, but I'm out of time.  I'll reply tomorrow after trying Upendra's suggestion of multiple named views.

Comment: I guess the problem is the definition of the right views. I don't know the way Upendra uses for views, but I think it could be done easier with UI Router methods. If you'd show me your templates, I could try to help you with it.

Comment: This did end up working once I tweaked the URLs in the state definitions.  I'll post the important bits of my code in another "answer."

Answer (score 2):

```
You can use following method to create separate views. 


    state('people.following',{
                    data:{
                          anyVar: {
                                    label: 'cp',
                                    text : 'anyText'
                                  }
                         },                     
                         views: {
                            'content@people': angularAMD.route({
                                template: infoView,
                                controller: 'custInfoCtrl',
                                controllerUrl: 'modules/custCtrl'
                            }),
                            'mobileView@people': angularAMD.route({
                                template: mobileView,
                                controller: 'mobileCtrl',
                                controllerUrl: 'modules/mobileBottomViewCtrl'
                            })
                        }
                    })

<pre>
 <div ui-view='contentArea'>   </div>    
  <div ui-view='mobileView'>    </div>  
</pre>
```

Comment: In this situation, is `<pre> ... </pre>` the template specified by the people state?  Is people an abstract state?  You method also doesn't seem to account for parameters; where would they be defined?

Comment: pre is of no use, 
state is not abstract but you can keep it abstract if needed..for parameters i just edited post

Answer (score 1):

RobYed pointed me in the right direction to figure out the right way to define my states.  Here's the bones of what I wound up with.

app.js:

```
.state('legislator', {
  url: "/legislator",
  templateUrl: "templates/legislator.header.html",
  abstract: true,
})

.state('legislator.profile', {
  url: "/{seq_no:int}/profile",
  templateUrl: "templates/legislator.profile.html",
  controller: "profileController"
})
```

templates/legislator.header.html:

```
<ion-nav-view animation="slide-left-right">
  <div class="bar bar-header" ng-controller="profileController">
    {{legislator.name}}
  </div>
  <div class="tabs tabs-striped tabs-top">
    <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="legislator.profile" ng-class="{selected: is('legislator.profile')}">
      {{'Profile' | translate}}
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="legislator.votes"   ng-class="{selected: is('legislator.votes')}">
      {{'Votes' | translate}}
    </a>
    <a class="tab-item" ui-sref="legislator.stats"   ng-class="{selected: is('legislator.stats')}">
      {{'Stats' | translate}}
    </a>
  </div>
  <div ui-view></div>
</ion-nav-view>
```

templates/legislator.profile.html:

```
<ion-content>
  <div class="bar bar-stable has-subheader" style="height:145px;">
    {{legislator.whatever}}
    Content Here
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

profileController.js:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp').controller('profileController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.legislator = $rootScope.legislators[$stateParams.seq_no-1];
});
```

Links from other states:

```
<a ui-sref="legislator.profile({seq_no:legislator.seq_num})"></a>
```

Comment: glad that I could help :)